# How to select all from table one based on a value, then select from same table with value from that table?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic

I have a table with users that can look like this. 
Where the Socialnr is empty in one or more rows.

```
Userid:1 Phone:12345 Email:test@test.com Socialnr:88776655
Userid:2 Phone:12345 Email:              Socialnr:
Userid:3 Phone:      Email:test@test.com Socialnr:
```

Lets say I only have the Socialnr from the start.
So from this I need to

`select * from users where socialnr=88776655`

but then I need to be able to select the two other rows as well based on the same email or phonenumber that I get from the first select.
I need separate rows.
Any input appreciated, thanks.

Based on Gordons answer I have this now with my real code.

```
SELECT u.* FROM appmanager.appusers u where u.userId='797' and u.personnrvh2='88776655' OR exists (select 1 from appmanager.appusers u2 where u2.userId='797' and u2.personnrvh2='88776655'  and (u2.emailvh2 = u.emailvh2 or u2.mobilvh2 = u.mobilvh2))
```

Ok so this was the solution, thanks a lot Gordon!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: oracle, sql-server, postgresql...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . based on your description, you can use `exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.Socialnr = 88776655 or
      exists (select 1
              from users u2
              where u2.Socialnr = 88776655 and
                    (u2.email = u.email or u2.phone = u.phone)
             );
```

If you wanted, you could also use window functions . . . assuming that each `email` and `phone` has one ultimate `Socialnr`

```
select u.*
from (select u.*,
             max(Socialnr) over (partition by email) as imputed_socialnr_email,
             max(Socialnr) over (partition by phone) as imputed_socialnr_phone
      from users u
     ) u
where 88776655 in (Socialnr, imputed_socialnr_email, imputed_socialnr_phone)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, Im almost there I think with you first solution. I get the right rows, but it is also showing rows with different userIds, not only userId 797 as i should. I will update my question with my real code that I have now.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the first solution was the one. Great!

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson . . . I understand neither the downvotes on your question nor the downvote on my answer.

Comment: No neither did I, but I´m very glad you helped me :-) Thanks again!

Comment: I think you need to add an exception such as `AND NOT u.email = ''` so that it doesn't check against empty column values if a row contains a social number, but no email. Otherwise it will list all rows that have no email.